# Is There any way to save a frozen wine program without closing it? (Fl studio for Ex.) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, ram

So i had a wine program open, and it froze, it dosen't  crash, it just turns dark gray and unresponsive, i really don't want to close it, i have a very  important unsaved project, maybe distributing the RAM? thanks.

Comment: Are you out of RAM? What does `top` show? You will most likely have to close the project.

Comment: im very sure its not my ram, because i can open  up to  4 instances of the same program at the same time   and they all run easy peazy, while just one is frozen.

Comment: Yeah. You have to close the program and hoped it may have saved, because Wine sounds like it crashed. If you haven't saved recently *that is your fault*, sorry to say, as you shouldn't expect Wine to be perfectly stable all the time.